# Sending Push Notification using javaScript in Parse

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, parse-platform, push-notification

Actually we are done with sending push notification from mobile  to mobile  & parse to mobile using parse quires. Now we are trying to send push notification from web application to mobile device using Javascript.

```
 function authentication() {

  Parse.$ = jQuery;

  // Initialize Parse with your Parse application javascript keys
  Parse.initialize("app key",
                   "javascript key");

    Parse.Push.send({
          //where: pushQuery,
          channels: [ "Demo","Done" ],
          data: {
          alert : "Hello word" 
    }}, { success: function() {
          // Push was successful 
          alert : "Push was successful"
        //  debugger;
        },
          error: function(error) {


        }}).then (function(error) {
          //Marks this promise as fulfilled, 
          //firing any callbacks waiting on it.


        });


}
```

Plz Guide us,we are new to javascript.
we getting error like this

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/push 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: Did you succeded with this task? I'm trying to do the same and i would like to know if you made this work.

Comment: @DiogoNunes thanks for reply,completed this task but we trying to send image from web(javascript) to mobile through push notification

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987340/send-a-sound-file-or-image-as-push-notification-using-gcm

Comment: @DiogoNunes.but  we are using with Parse.com

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate **Client Push Enabled** in the Push Notifications settings of your Parse app ?

> However, if you decide to send notifications from the JavaScript SDK outside of Cloud Code or any of the other client SDKs, you will need to set Client Push Enabled in the Push Notifications settings of your Parse app.

From: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes

Note that you shouldn't send notification from any clients, instead trigger the notifications from cloud code

> However, be sure you understand that enabling Client Push can lead to a security vulnerability in your app, as outlined on our blog. We recommend that you enable Client Push for testing purposes only, and move your push notification logic into Cloud Code when your app is ready to go into production.

Answer (score 0):

I am also sending the notification from javascript to Mobile using parse.

My code is almost similar to you except one thing,

Instead of this

```
Parse.initialize("app key",
                   "javascript key");
```

I am using

```
Parse.initialize("APP_ID", "API_KEY", "JAVASCRIPT KEY");
```

My complete code is.. though I am using node.js you can relate to corresponding code.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                   query.equalTo('installationId', parseInstallationId);

                      Parse.Push.send({
                        where: query, // Set our Installation query
                        data: {
                          alert: "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly." 
                        }
                      }, {
                        success: function() {
                          // Push was successful
                          console.log('successful');
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                          // Handle error
                          console.log('error');
                        }
                });
```