# Image push notification with Google cloud messaging

Tags: php, android, image, google-cloud-messaging

How to attach the image in push notification with Google Cloud Messaging ..Is it is possible to attach image, can any one tell how to attach..(or) it is possible like attach image in the form of URL/Text.. please provide me some sample example..

Comment: No men it's not possible better to used `Parse` or `Urbenship` third party Notifications

Comment: can you tell me.As i'm new to this concept can you provide me some sample example..

Comment: Go to official [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCM send image instead of message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436624/gcm-send-image-instead-of-message)

Comment: @eran i have seen that seen that i can't understand and even the links are not working in that..

Comment: @vinayManeti There are working links in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Maximum size of the push message can be upto 4KB. Therefore it is recommended to put the image on server somewhere and pass the url link of that image via push.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the correct approach. Each `GCM` message is limited to `4KB` of data, so unless you want to send messages as it was somekind of `TCP` protocol, you shouldn't use it.

Sending images is probably better to be done with a `HTTP POST` request to the remote server (as the `GCM` architecture requires), and afterwards process it.

Comment: Sure, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post

Comment: i have followed this tutorial to send the message http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Sure, you'll have to process that request in the server side written in `PHP`, but you want to send it through an `Android` app, if I understood it correctly. Have a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php