# Sending images via GCM android chat application

Tags: android, mobile, google-cloud-messaging

Any one knows how to send Images through android chat application using GCM. I have not found any proper answer for this question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could have at least add some code to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send Image in the payload of the GCM, but the size must be less then 4096 Byte. Here is a list of [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436833/1596703).

**Suggestion: It is better to send a link of this image using GCM after that you can retrieve the image from this link in the client side. In this way you can improve the response time for Group/Room messaging.**

Comment: how to send larger files having size more than 4096 kb?.

Comment: see my suggestion. It that case send the link of that Image.

Comment: I am currently done by uploading the  images to server and sending the uploaded image link to the user. But i don't get an idea on how to manage the received image.

Comment: Is there any way to create multiple image views and managing the received images in android chat  application

Comment: yes you can, use relative or framelayout for multiple image view.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion given by BeingMIAkashs is correct. 
You can send, a URL from GCM server to the target device. The client app, can then perform a download of your image. Once the image is downloaded, then you can create a notification in your app and show it to the user.